# What happens if a bill passes the House with a provision that sunsets before the Senate hears it?

Tags: united-states, congress, taxes, legislation

The House passed [HR 7024](https://www.congress.gov/bill/118th-congress/house-bill/7024) today (Jan. 31st) which has a provision that expires a tax credit today - on the 31st. Since the Senate has not received the Bill, what happens to the date that has now passed?

Answer (score 3):

"Expiring" a tax credit means that the credit can no longer be claimed after the expiration date.  From the bill itself, section 602(h):

> no credit or refund of any COVID-related employee retention tax credit shall be allowed or made after January 31, 2024, unless a claim for such credit or refund is filed by the taxpayer on or before such date.

So if the Senate passes it in two weeks without changing that date (and then it immediately gets signed into law) any claims which came in after the specified date are discarded.  The same thing would happen (at the appropriate dates) if the date was in the future or in the past relative to when it becomes law.

Answer (score 1):

The [COVID Employee Retention Credit](https://www.irs.gov/coronavirus/frequently-asked-questions-about-the-employee-retention-credit) is a "refundable tax credit for certain eligible businesses and tax-exempt organizations." which turned into hotbed of scams and fraud.  The IRS [stopped processing](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/to-protect-taxpayers-from-scams-irs-orders-immediate-stop-to-new-employee-retention-credit-processing-amid-surge-of-questionable-claims-concerns-from-tax-pros) new ERC claims last fall and (as of January 25th the [moratorium was still in effect](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/irs-continues-work-on-employee-retention-credit-new-irs-ci-education-sessions-come-as-agency-urges-businesses-to-review-vdp-withdrawal-program-for-questionable-claims)).  Since the IRS isn't processing new claims it's kind of a moot point.